# SQL Query changing based on parameters

Tags: sql

a true IF...THEN statement would be useful here, but I am not aware of one.  I have the user passing in 2 parameters (cfk_in and senr_in) into my query, and based on whether the param is Y or N, I will change my query, here is my current query:

```
select a.course_id, a.topic_code
from course_sections a,
 statuses b
where a.course_id = b.course_id
  and term = upper('2010FALL')
  and status = 'P' and pos = 1
```

So this is pretty simple and would give me all sections and topic codes for a particular term.  If the user passes in both params as 'N', I would like to just keep it at the above query.  If the user passes in cfk_in = 'Y' and senr_in = 'N' then I would like to add "and a.topic_code = 'CFK%'", and like wise if the user passes in cfk_in = 'N' and senr_in = 'Y', I would like to add "and a.topic_code = 'SENR'".  I am not allowing them to pass both in as 'Y'.

Is there a way to do this in one query?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: is this within a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
[your query...]
and ((cfk_in = 'N' and senr_in = 'N') or
     (cfk_in = 'Y' and senr_in = 'N' and a.topic_code like 'CFK%') or
     (cfk_in = 'N' and senr_in = 'Y' and a.topic_code = 'SENR'))
```

This will also disallow passing both parameters as `'Y'`, as that would return no results. If `cfk_in` and `senr_in` aren't actual fields in your table, then mark them as bind variables:

```
[your query...]
and ((:cfk_in = 'N' and :senr_in = 'N') or
     (:cfk_in = 'Y' and :senr_in = 'N' and a.topic_code like 'CFK%') or
     (:cfk_in = 'N' and :senr_in = 'Y' and a.topic_code = 'SENR'))
```

Or with Java:

```
[your query...]
and ((? = 'N' and ? = 'N') or
     (? = 'Y' and ? = 'N' and a.topic_code like 'CFK%') or
     (? = 'N' and ? = 'Y' and a.topic_code = 'SENR'))
```

... binding `cfk_in` at indexes 1, 3, 5, and `senr_in` at indexes 2, 4, 6

N.B: I think you meant to filter `a.topic_code like 'CFK%'`, not `a.topic_code = 'CFK%'`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this in one query?

Absolutely. You can use `OR` to "mask out" parts of your query. For example,

```
AND (senr_in <> 'N' OR a.topic_code = 'CFK%')
```

will pay attention to `topic_code` only when `senr_in = 'N'`. Otherwise, the whole subexpression would evaluate to `true`, effectively excluding itself from the query condition.

Comment: While this clever solution is less verbose, I tend to feel that these kinds of boolean expressions are highly unreadable and difficult to change correctly, when needed...

Comment: @LukasEder This depends entirely on the way the expression is structured. When properly formatted and commented, it should not cause any issues: after all, this relatively well-known "idiom" with "masking" boolean expressions is applicable both inside and outside of the SQL query language, so it is often just instantly familiar.

Comment: Actually, your expression isn't correct, because if `cfk_in = 'N' and senr_in = 'N'`, no additional filter should be applied. I agree with the "relatively well-known idiom". Still I find this more difficult to modify, than if the canonical expression is used. But I guess that's a matter of taste...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is a way. You could use your parameters in your where condition, like so:

```
select a.course_id, a.topic_code
from course_sections a,
 statuses b
where a.course_id = b.course_id
  and term = upper('2010FALL')
  and status = 'P' and pos = 1
  and ((cfk_in = 'Y' and senr_in = 'N' and a.topic_code like 'CFK%') or      
       (cfk_in = 'N' and senr_in = 'Y' and a.topic_code = 'SENR') or
       (cfk_in = 'N' and senr_in = 'N'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in one query.
Simpy add the following to your where clause:
(Note, I altered your a.topic_code = 'CFK%' to a.topic_code LIKE 'CFK%')

```
AND (@cfk_in = 'N' OR (@cfk_in = 'Y' AND a.topic_code LIKE 'CFK%'))
AND (@senr_in = 'N' OR (@senr_in = 'Y' AND a.topic_code = 'SENR'))
```